# How could i achieve expoential in salesforce with decimal power

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

((82125.49845) / (0 + 1)) * ((1 + ((2.84*1)/100)) / (1 + ((2.84*1)/100) + 0.005))^(14.083)

The above calculation gives me the correct value 76 703.2452


 But when i does this stuff in salesforce using the Math.pow it doesn't gives me the exact result and help me to sort it out and below are the options which i used in salesforce apex class


1) System.debug('>>> pow=' + Math.pow((82125.49845 / (0 + 1)) * ((1 + ((2.84*1)/100)) / (1 + ((2.84*1)/100) + 0.005).doubleValue(),14.0832.doubleValue());


2) System.debug('>>> final=' +(82125.49845 / (0 + 1)) * ((1 + ((2.84*1)/100)) / (1 + ((2.84*1)/100) + 0.005)).pow(14.0832));

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `pow` function only works with `Double`s, which have less precision than the `Decimal` type for Real number calculations.

The `Math` class does support exponentiation with `Decimal`s using natural exponents and natural logarithms though, so this should work for you:

```
Math.exp ( Math.log ((82125.49845) / (0 + 1)) + 14.083 * Math.log ((1 + ((2.84*1)/100)) / (1 + ((2.84*1)/100) + 0.005)) )
```